# Definition of a module in Lang's Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I have a question regarding the definition of a left module in Lang's Algebra. I believe it is missing, but I wanted to confirm here. Here is the definition of a left module in Lang's Algebra. I am quoting it verbatim (I have the third revision edition, and this is on page 117):

> Let $A$ be a ring. A left module over $A,$ or a left $A$-module $M$ is an abelian group, usually written additively, together with an operation of $A$ on $M$ (viewing $A$ as a multiplicative monoid by **RI 2**) such that, for all $a, b \in A$ and $x, y \in M$ we have
> $(a+b)x=ax + bx$ and $a(x+y)=ax+ay$.

Now for the sake of completeness, let me write what he means by **RI 2**, which is one of the three ring axioms when he defines a ring for the first time:

> The multiplication is associative, and has a unit element.

**In addition to everything he has said in the definition, doesn't he also need to say that $(ab)x=a(bx)?$**

Answer (score 1):

This is implied already. We view $A$ as a multiplicative monoid, as suggested. Then an operation of $A$ on $M$ is a monoid homomorphism $\varphi\colon A\rightarrow M^M$. For $a\in A$ and $x\in M$, we denote $\varphi(a)(x)=ax$. Then, for $a,b\in A$ and $x\in X$, $$(ab)x=\varphi(ab)(x)=(\varphi(a)\circ\varphi(b))(x)=\varphi(a)(\varphi(b)(x))=a(bx).$$
The second equality holds, because $\varphi$ is a monoid homomorphism. Note that we also get $1x=\varphi(1)(x)=\operatorname{id}_M(x)=x$ for $x\in M$, where $1$ is the unit in $A$, for the same reason. This recovers the "usual" axioms for a module.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What exactly do you mean by M^M? Also, I’ve never heard of the word “operation” used in place of “action.” (What you are describing looks to me like a group, or in this case monoid specifically, action. I thought “operation” meant just a map, whereas “action” had the desired property I am after. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: $M^M$ is notation for the set of functions from $M$ to $M.$

Comment: Yes, I'm using operation and action synonymously. I'm not sure what Lang's convention for the terminology is, but this is the only sensible thing he could mean in this context.

Comment: I understand: thank you Thorgott and Chris Leary.